# Rank permutation with increasing runs and constraints

Tags: java, arrays, math, permutation, ranking

I want to rank permutations which have serveral increasing runs. A increasing run is a sequence of permutation elements in the following form `perm[i] < perm[i+1]`. The constraint is that `perm[i+1] - perm[i] <= maxDistance` inside increasing runs. A turningpoint at index `i` describes following: `perm[i-1] > perm[i]`.

Example `1234`, `maxDistance = 2`, `turning point at index 2`

Valid permutations:

`1324`,`2413`,`3412`

Invalid permuations:

`1423` greater MaxDistance

`1243` turning point at index 3

Here is my attempt: which gives me rank `1` for `1324`, rank `3` for `2413`, rank `4` for `3412` but ranking starts with 0. But i dont know why the ranks are not `0,1,2`. How can i rank this kind of permutations? Thank you in advance.

```
public BigInteger calcRank(int[] perm, int maxDistance){
  BigInteger rank = BigInteger.ZERO;
  BigInteger multipler = BigInteger.ONE;

  List<Integer> turns = calcTurns(perm);

  int[] numbers = getNumbers(perm.length);

  for(int j=0,last=-1,q=0;j<perm.length && j<turns.get(turns.size()-1);j++){

    int all=0;
    int avail=0;

    if(j == turns.get(q)){
      for(int l=0;l<numbers.length;l++){
        if(numbers[l] != -1){
          last = l;
          break;
        }
      }
      q++;
    }

    for(int k=last,org=last;k < numbers.length;k++){
      if(numbers[k] == -1){
        continue;
      }

      if(all == maxDistance || numbers[org]+maxDistance < numbers[k]){
        break;
      }

      if(numbers[k] == perm[j]){
        avail = all;
        numbers[k] = -1;
        for(int l=k+1;l<numbers.length;l++){
          if(numbers[l] != -1){
            last = l;
          }
        }
      }
      all++;
    }
    rank = rank.add(multipler.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(avail)));
    multipler = multipler.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(all));
  }

  return rank;
}

private List<Integer> calcTurns(int[] perm){
  List<Integer> out=new ArrayList<>();

  out.add(0);

  for(int i=1;i<perm.length;i++){
    if(perm[i-1] > perm[i]){
      out.add(i);
    }
  }

  return out;
}

private int[] getNumbers(int n){
  int[] out = new int[n];

  for(int i=1; i <= n;i++){
    out[i-1] = i;
  }

  return out;
}
```

Comment: What is by your definition the rank of a permutation? You gave the examples `1324 -> 1`, `2413 -> 2` and `3412 -> 4` but apparently wish for `1324 -> 0`, `2413 -> 1` and `3412 -> 2`. How do you define the _rank_?

Comment: If you write all valid permutations lexicographical ordered line after line then `1324` is line `0`, `2413` is line `1`, etc. The Rank describes the line number in the lexicographical ordered list of vaild permutations.

Comment: Alright. So I think your idea is the following: For a given permutation you want to find its index in the lexicographical ordered list of all permutations that fulfill some given constraints (_maximum distance_ and _turning points_). If that's the case: Finding a remotely efficient algorithm for that search is certainly not trivial at all, and would - if at all - be better asked for on cs.stackexchange.com. If I misunderstood you, please correct me.